# Does scala.sys.process block on stream processing threads?

Tags: scala, asynchronous, thread-safety

The Scala external process library, `scala.sys.process`, allows to run an external process (*e.g.* `ls`) and attach some processing functions to `stdout` and `stderr`. For example:

```
Seq("ls" ".").run(new ProcessIO(os => os.close(), is => f(is), is => g(is))).exitValue()
```

This runs `ls .` and runs some functions `f` and `g` on its `stdout` and `stderr`. Documentation says that  `f` and `g` are executed in separate threads.

My question is, will `.exitValue()` block just until `ls` exits, or until not only `ls` exits but also those threads which run `f` and `g` are done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple experiment:

```
def doStuff(sleepFor: Long): Unit = {
  val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis
  val result = Seq("ls", ".").run(
    new ProcessIO(
      { os: OutputStream => os.close() },
      { is: InputStream => Thread.sleep(sleepFor); is.close() },
      { is: InputStream => Thread.sleep(sleepFor); is.close() }
    )
  ).exitValue
  val finishTime = System.currentTimeMillis
  println(s"Result = $result, took ${ finishTime - startTime }ms")
}
```

When invoked, if we see that it took at least around `sleepFor`ms, it almost certainly blocked until the functions on standard out and standard error completed (especially if this holds for two very different values of `sleepFor`).

In an SBT console:

```
scala> doStuff(1000)
Result = 0, took 1002ms

scala> doStuff(10000)
Result = 0, took 10002ms
```

Experimentally verified that `.run().exitValue` blocks until the functions on input and output complete.

[Tracing through the source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/sys/process/Process.scala#L39) (as of 2.13, but earlier versions should be similar), we see that a `Seq[String]` ultimately creates a `Simple` `ProcessBuilder`, which when run leads to a [`SimpleProcess`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/sys/process/ProcessImpl.scala#L258):

```
override def exitValue() = {
  try p.waitFor()                   // wait for the process to terminate
  finally interrupt()
  outputThreads foreach (_.join())  // this ensures that all output is complete before returning (waitFor does not ensure this)

  p.exitValue()
```

The standard out/error processor threads are in `outputThreads` and are `join`ed, which blocks until both threads are complete.

Side note: `scala.sys.process` is a pretty strong contender for most archaic API in the standard library, given that it predates the introduction of the `Future` API and the functions which result in a stream/lazy list of output lines encode the exit code as a bare `RuntimeException` where the message has to be parsed to extract the exit code (rather than a distinguished exception or even better a stream of `Either[ExitWithErrorException, String]`).

Comment: Thank you ! I wonder, if it is possible to extract this fact from manuals, or perhaps from a specification? Your experiment is convincing, but it is not a proof... (Although, one might say, that the behavior which you observed is the reasonable one.)

Comment: I've edited it with the commented code from `scala/scala` on github demonstrating that it does in fact wait until both processing threads are complete.

Comment: The link should be to ProcessImpl, not ProcessBuilderImpl. This is the correct link: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/sys/process/ProcessImpl.scala#L258